# Silverlight - Wait for async task to complete

Tags: c#, silverlight

Here is what i have done so far:

All of the below code will get looped through and different URL's will be sent each time. I want to be able to call the address in the loop and then wait for it to complete and then call the completed method.

**I have created my URI**

```
Uri address = new Uri("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/V1/Imagery/Metadata/OrdnanceSurvey/" + latitude + "," + longitude + "?+zl=" + zoomLevel + "&key=""");
```

**I have then told it where to call when the operation has complete**

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += WebClientDownloadString_Complete;
webClient.DownloadStringAsync(address);
```

**Then i set up what to happen when the operation has completed**

```
    private void WebClientDownloadString_Complete(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {

            string html = e.Result;

            string[] parts = html.Split(',');
            string[] URLs = parts[7].Split('"');
            URL = URLs[3].Replace("{subdomain}", "t0").Replace("{quadkey}", qk.Key).Replace(@"\", string.Empty);


        }
    }
```

Is there a way so that when the webclient calls the URL I wait till the operation has completed and it calls the completed method?

Answer (score 0):

The *easy* way to do this is to just use [`DownloadString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `DownloadStringAsync`. The `DownloadString` call will block (make sure to run it on a background thread!) and you can loop as you expect.

Your other option is to create a `TaskCompletionSource` and set it in your event handler.

```
private TaskCompletionSource<bool> currentTask;

private async Task GetURLs()
{
    while (someCondition)
    {
        currentTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += WebClientDownloadString_Complete;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(address);

        await currentTask;
    }
}

private void WebClientDownloadString_Complete(...)
{
    //Process completion

    //C# 6 null check
    curentTask?.TrySetValue(true);
}
```

"GetURLS" will block asynchronously until the tasks value is set, and then allow the while loop to continue. This has the advantage of not needing an explicit background thread.

Comment: I am not able to use the async keyword in VS2010.

Comment: @BenClarke .NET 4.5 feature, you'll need at least VS2012 to use it. If you can't go that high, I would stick with a blocking method

Answer (score 0):

The code that you put up already does just that - you created your WebClient, you set an event handler to its completed method, and you start the download. If you want to wait for it to finish, all you need to do is let your method end, and control will pass back to the Silverlight framework which will do your waiting for you.

The other way to do this would be to use the `async` and `await` keywords, which your framework appears to support. Simply put, you might be able to put an `await` keyword before your method call to `DownloadStringAsync`, which will cause the system to wait for the download (and go on to other tasks), pull out the string once the download completes, and continue as usual:

```
string html = await webClient.DownloadStringAsync(address);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is i need to wait just after the `webClient.DownloadStringAsync(address);` as below that it does a return for the URL created. The await keyword that you have shown does not work for me im in VS2010

Comment: Then just do the requests after you parse them in your callback.

Answer (score -1):

Wanted to do this myself some time ago.
Here is how I did it:

```
            // create a notifier which tells us when the download is finished
            // in .net 4.5 DownloadFileTaskAsync can be used instead which simplyfies this task
            AutoResetEvent notifier = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += (object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                notifier.Set();
            };

            try
            { 

                client.DownloadFileAsync(downloadUrl, destination);
                // wait for download to finish
                notifier.WaitOne();
             ...
```

Comment: Good method, but a `TaskCompletionSource` is a little nicer (and doesn't block the calling thread)

Comment: I guess if he can use DownloadFileTaskAsync he could do it even nicer ;)